# How do I make a random spawn outside a specific area

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to make this basic little game where there is a platform in the middle of the screen and there are circles that spawn randomly around the area when you touch it just like food items in the game snake. My only problem is that sometimes the circle will spawn inside the platform in the middle making it impossible to touch. I'm using the random function for an x and y value to be in the play area so each time it spawns it's given a random location. Is there any way to make sure it doesn't show up in the specific platform in the middle? I'm doing this in basic JavaScript in p5js

```
function coin () {
    this.x = random (16, width-16);
    this.y = random (16, height-91);

    this.show = function() {
        ellipse (this.x, this.y, 32, 32);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please put you code inside the post so that others know how to guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would do this in your head. Try to write out a set of steps, in English (not in code) that you follow when you come up with a random number from two ranges.

How I'd do it is something like this:

- Flip a coin to decide which side the number should come from.
- Now that a side is chosen, then use the plain old `random()` function to generate a number from that range.

For example, let's say I want to choose a number from 1-30, but I don't want 11-19 to be options. Here's how I'd do that:

```
var number;
if(random() < .5){
  number = random(1, 10);
}
else{
  number = random(20, 30);
}
```

The `if(random() < .5)` line is flipping a coin, so you select each range 50% of the time. You might want to adjust this percentage if your ranges are not equal size.

You could also come up with a random number until it's outside the range you want. Something like this:

```
var number = random(1, 30);
while(number >= 11 && number <=19){
  number = random(1, 30);
}
```

Comment: So how would I then set these 2 numbers to an x and y value and set those numbers inside of the ellipse? The range I'm trying to stay out of is, for x, is between width/4+16 (radius of ellipse) and 466, and for y its between 266 and 234. I feel like if I did it that way it wouldn't be able to spawn in between the width/4 and 466 at all, I tried doing an if statement, if the x was between that AND between the y' s I'm trying to stay out of, it would create a new one

Comment: @Stacktempacc The real lesson is that you need to [break your problem down](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and think about how you'd do this in your head, before even thinking about implementing it with code.

Comment: Nvm I got it now ty